# Evaluate based on Truth value of other rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
data=[{
    'directors': 'Ertil Altanaj',
    'director_score': 0.7,
}, {
    'directors': 'Erbil Altanaj',
    'director_score': 0.9,
}, {
    'directors': 'Richard Klemann',
    'director_score': 1.0,
}]
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

To determine whether something has a 'matched score' I can do something like:

```
df['director_score_match'] = df.director_score >= 0.90

         directors  director_score  director_score_match
0    Ertil Altanaj             0.7                 False
1    Erbil Altanaj             0.9                  True
2  Richard Klemann             1.0                  True
```

I would like to determine if an other row (i.e., any other row excluding itself) has a `True` value for that field. For example, the result should be:

```
         directors  director_score  director_score_match      director_score_other_match
0    Ertil Altanaj             0.7                 False      True
1    Erbil Altanaj             0.9                 True       True
2  Richard Klemann             1.0                 True       True
```

How would I do that calculation in pandas?

Comment: Could you be more specific? You have just one column, which is of ```bool``` type, how do you define other field having ```True``` value?

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski it would be if any rows eval to `True` other than the given row. So row 0, has 1,2 evaluate to True, row 1 has 2 evaluate to True, row 3 has 2 evaluate to True.

Comment: Also what is ```other``` there? Row-wise, column-wise, some sort of grouping?

Comment: `other` would just mean row with index != self

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```py
df['director_score_other_match']=df['director_score_match'].astype(int).lt(df['director_score_match'].astype(int).sum())
```

Some explanation:

You convert `bool` to `int` (`1/0`). Then the only case when field should be `False` is when either all are `False` or this single one is `True` - hence you make sure, that the current `1/0` is less than the total sum.

Comment: @Gregorz -- wow, that's pretty tricky / a long one-liner. Would the above approach be preferably to throwing it into a function? Do you usually get these real long one-liners in pandas?

Comment: Depends on your preference- this one I would keep as it is. It's not very long and it's pretty specific. Unless obviously you want to make it reusable- then function is the way to go indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
df['director_score_other_match'] = df['director_score_match'].apply(lambda x: not(x))
```

Comment: this is wrong, that's just inverting the truth value (also, why would you need a lambda for that)? Please re-read the question.

Comment: Sorry i took it wrong, before even the last value was `False` , i will correct the code